# Clarification on a closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1196/907) was closed as off-topic as "Technical Support." Could someone explain why?

The OP isn't asking for technical support on fixing hardware.

He is looking for hardware to use with a mobile device (smartphone or tablet) that would provide the ability to test network cabling, either copper or fiber but preferably both.

Maybe the question isn't as clear as it could be and I have more background into what is being asked (we were one of the sites that the OP stopped at on the way here and we were the ones to direct him here), but that seems to be exactly the type of question that would fit on this site.

Am I wrong? If so, do please let me know how so I will better understand when to direct people here or not.

Comment: I don't think that was the right reason to use, but at the same time it certainly doesn't have enough information.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you tell him that, I think the OP will try to fix it (he tried to get it to fit three different times on our site and we weren't the first one he tried). Right now he has the impression he shouldn't even try here.

Comment: Did I hit the wrong button and then miss an explanation? Damn. OK, my fault. I can't do anything about it right now, but @Undo might be able to. If not, I'm on it tomorrow morning.

Comment: @ArtOfCode, maybe wrong button, but no he didn't try to explain. This is at least the third SE site he tried posting on today (and he tried three separate times on our site) so I think he is a bit frustrated. I am just going to bat for new user feeling a bit adrift on SE (and one who probably isn't familiar with meta). I was a new user once too (and still am in many respects).

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I edited the question here to include content from the three questions he posted on [networkengineering.se] or their comments. Still needs approval though.